# TextInput length counter in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput with maxLength 100 in my scene, and I want to add a counter below which shows something like "38/100", auto-updating with 'onChangeText'.

So I have to figure out the length of the input value, somehow store it in this.state.textLength while storing the value itself to this.state.text, but I don't know how to do this in "onChangeText = {(text) => ...}" function.

Here is my simplified code:

```
export class RequestScene extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state={
      text: '',
      textLength: 0,
      category: '',
      time: ''
    };
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
        <View style={{
            height: 200
        }}>
            <TextInput style={{
                height: 200,
                width: 360,
                borderColor: 'lightgray',
                borderWidth: 1,
                padding: 3,
                borderRadius: 3,
                fontSize: 24}}
                maxLength={100}
                placeholder='무슨 상황인지 간단하게 써주세요'
                multiline={true}

                // this is where I am stuck. What should I do with 'textLength'?
                onChangeText={
                    (text)=>this.setState({text})
                    (text)=>this.setState({textLength})
                }
            />
            <Text style={{
                fontSize:10,
                color:'lightgrey',
                textAlign: 'right'
            }}> 
                // currently this counter only shows '0/100'
                {this.state.textLength}/100 
            </Text>
```

Answer (score 7):

The `onChangeText()` function returns a string. You can do something like:

```js
const maxLength = 100;
this.setState({
  textLength: maxLength - text.length,
  text, // same as `text: text`
});
```

Comment: do you mean:
    onChangeText={
        const textLength = text.length; 
        const sub = 100 - textLength; 
        this.setState({textLength: sub});
        this.setState({text: text});
    }

Comment: Yes, but remember to feed the argument, i.e. (text) => { ... }

Answer (score 0):

To make your code easier to read, you can call a separate method within your onChangeText handler which updates `textLength` the following way:

```
export class RequestScene extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.maxLength = 100;

    this.state={
      textLength: 0,
    };
  }

  onChangeText(text){
    this.setState({
      textLength: this.maxLength - text.length
    });
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
        <View style={{
            height: 200
        }}>
            <TextInput style={{
                height: 200,
                width: 360,
                borderColor: 'lightgray',
                borderWidth: 1,
                padding: 3,
                borderRadius: 3,
                fontSize: 24}}
                maxLength={100}
                placeholder='무슨 상황인지 간단하게 써주세요'
                multiline={true}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText.bind(this)}
            />
            <Text style={{
                fontSize:10,
                color:'lightgrey',
                textAlign: 'right'
            }}> 
                // currently this counter only shows '0/100'
                {this.state.textLength}/100 
            </Text>
         </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get length of input field try

```
handleEmailOtp = emailOtpString => {
this.setState({emailOtp: emailOtpString});
const otpLength = emailOtpString.length.toString(); //here
otpLength == 6
  ? this.setState({otpTyped: true})
  : this.setState({otpTyped: false});
```

};

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ''
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
        <TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1 }} numberOfLines={3} maxLength={100} multiline={true} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text: text })} />
        <Text>{100 - this.state.text.length}/100 Characters</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/4733879) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!